# Is iCloud email address different from me.com address?

Tags: icloud, email, macos, apple-id

I have a me.com address that works on my iPad and on my Mac.

However, I am trying to set up iCloud to sync all of my devices on my Mac using the instructions found here, http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/mac.html

When I get to the second part of step 2 and check the Mail radio-box, I get a pop-up asking me to create an iCloud email address. I enter my me.com address and get this message, "This email address is already taken. Try picking a new one."

Am I supposed to create a SECOND me.com address for iCloud? Should my current me.com address work? Won't 2 addresses just confuse things further? What can I do to troubleshoot?

<sup>A side-note. Last night I successfully migrated data from gmail to my me.com calendar and address book. Everything worked successfully on my Mac but I cannot see any of the updates on my iPad. I want these updates on my Mac to push onto my iPad and I wonder if this issue is creating the problem. Everything seems to be working on the individual devices just not on the Cloud.</sup>

Comment: Where did you get your me.com address from? Have you tried to log into icloud.com with this address (and the corresponding password) yet?

Comment: I created my me.com address on my iPad. Yes, I can log into iCloud on both my Mac and my iPad with the address and password (and have received new mail messages from Apple that I can see and read on both devices).

Comment: Then you already have an iCloud account and don't need to create another one.

Comment: That's what I think too but I can't get the Cloud to function on my Mac. I don't have the little Cloud symbol anywhere in Safari and my devices aren't syncing? Is it something else? I can get to iCloud via Safari via the web page. But when I go to Apple-System Preferences-iCloud, I can't go any further....

Comment: Is there another way to get iCloud set up on my Mac? It is not on my dashboard, screen, anywhere on my Mac. Oh, and if I don't check the Mail radio box on Step 2 I can't go any further either. Thanks, by the way, for your time and help.

Comment: What does "can't go any further" mean in detail? In the iCloud pref pane you should either see a list of services (like Mail, Calendar etc.) meaning you are already logged in or a prompt for user id and password. If you are logged in, make sure to enable Document syncing. If this doesn't help, please post a screenshot of your iCloud preference pane.

Comment: Here's my theory on this new email suffix. First they had mac, then moved to me, now icloud. I think Apple links them all if you predate the new one. So if you had a mark@mac.com email address and it's been kept active, you would have gotten an me and now an icloud; all being linked together. But if you never created an mac account, you can't use that alongside your given me and icloud accounts. Same goes for those that didn't sign up with MobileMe or iCloud when it was first made public. So those that signed up with iCloud now, will only ever get icloud suffixes. Until Apple makes a new one.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't migrate your old MobileMe account to iCloud before it expired last june you may be locked out of that old account.

Here is the list of things you can still do if your MobileMe email expired and how to add a new email address to that Apple ID.

- [Can I use my MobileMe account for Apple services without moving to iCloud?](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2968)